# Custom Dock in Gimp

Tags: gimp

In GIMP: is there a way how to make my own custom dock (toolbar) where a could put my most used functions?

Something like this:

1. Create new empty dock or toolbar
2. Somehow set what functions will be in it 
   (any of the functions, no matter it has an icon or where in menus is located)

I'd like to have it so I don't have to search in menus every time I need something. I'm aware that I can make keyboard shortcuts but they are difficult to remember since I don't use Gimp every day. I'm used to this from Corel Photopaint and I think it is really useful.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GIMP 2.8, you can only customize the dockable dialogs - by dragging then around, and in another level, customize tool presets and make use of the tags in the presets dialog to quckly access paint-modes with set brushes, gradients and painting dynamics - so, keeping the tool-presets dialog around, and appropriately using the tags can give you quick access to these settings.

You can't, however, add additional menu entries or icons to select particular plug-ins (filters) - and access those from any of the dockable dialogs. without rebuilding GIMP, you could edit the XML files at /usr/share/gimp/2.0/menus to customize your menus.

In the master branch, the unstable "GIMP 2.9" which will eventually become GIMP 2.10, there is a "search" action implemented, initiated by pressing the `/` character that will probably make it for the need to quickly find-out any operations wanted.